# Astro build getting failed in github workflow build step with error jekyll::Converters::Scss encountered an error while converting .css file':

Tags: css, github-actions, aws-amplify, astrojs

Having astro blog domain which is hodted in Route53 using AWS Amplify and and when I do commit and push the code in github repo then it trigger the build which is failing in *Build with Jekyll* steps and giving some css parsing issue.

```
    GitHub Pages: github-pages v228
      GitHub Pages: jekyll v3.9.3
             Theme: jekyll-theme-primer
      Theme source: /usr/local/bundle/gems/jekyll-theme-primer-0.6.0
         Requiring: jekyll-github-metadata
To use retry middleware with Faraday v2.0+, install `faraday-retry` gem
  Conversion error: Jekyll::Converters::Scss encountered an error while converting 'assets/css/style.scss':
                    No such file or directory @ dir_chdir - /github/workspace/docs
/usr/local/bundle/gems/jekyll-sass-converter-1.5.2/lib/jekyll/converters/scss.rb:86:in `chdir': No such file or directory @ dir_chdir - /github/workspace/docs (Errno::ENOENT)
```

#### **css/style.css**

```css
:root {
  --accent: grey;
}

@supports font-format(woff2) {
  @font-face {
    font-family: 'Roboto';
    src: url('../fonts//Roboto-Black.woff2') format('woff2');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
  }
}

body {
  font-family: 'Roboto', 'Gill Sans', 'Gill Sans MT', Calibri, 'Trebuchet MS', sans-serif;
  font-size: 16px;
}
```

my doubt is the custom font, so remove the font line but build failed after it too.

someone can help me here?

[here is the complete log](https://github.com/xkeshav/blog/actions/runs/6435550179/job/17477043638)

also this is my package.json

```json
{
  "name": "grateful-galaxy",
  "type": "module",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "astro dev",
    "start": "astro dev",
    "build": "astro build",
    "preview": "astro preview",
    "astro": "astro"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@astrojs/mdx": "^0.17.2",
    "@astrojs/rss": "^2.1.1",
    "@astrojs/sitemap": "^1.1.0",
    "astro": "^3.2.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "typescript": "^5.2.2"
  }
}
```

tried `npm run build` which works fine in local.

---

#### Update

using AWS Amplify, so the build triggerd by AWS which run the workflowe in github and there see the build failig withe below error

```
                                 # Executing command: npm ci
2023-10-06T19:20:02.795Z [WARNING]: npm
2023-10-06T19:20:02.797Z [WARNING]: WARN EBADENGINE Unsupported engine {
                                    npm WARN EBADENGINE   package: '@astrojs/prism@3.0.0',
                                    npm WARN EBADENGINE   required: { node: '>=18.14.1' },
                                    npm WARN EBADENGINE   current: { node: 'v16.19.0', npm: '8.19.3' }
                                    npm WARN EBADENGINE }
                                    npm WARN EBADENGINE Unsupported engine {
                                    npm WARN EBADENGINE   package: '@astrojs/telemetry@3.0.2',
                                    npm WARN EBADENGINE   required: { node: '>=18.14.1' },
                                    npm WARN EBADENGINE   current: { node: 'v16.19.0', npm: '8.19.3' }
                                    npm WARN EBADENGINE }
2023-10-06T19:20:02.798Z [WARNING]: npm
2023-10-06T19:20:02.798Z [WARNING]: WARN EBADENGINE Unsupported engine {
                                    npm WARN EBADENGINE   package: 'astro@3.2.0',
                                    npm WARN EBADENGINE   required: { node: '>=18.14.1', npm: '>=6.14.0' },
                                    npm WARN EBADENGINE   current: { node: 'v16.19.0', npm: '8.19.3' }
                                    npm WARN EBADENGINE }
2023-10-06T19:20:15.722Z [INFO]: added 576 packages, and audited 577 packages in 16s
2023-10-06T19:20:15.726Z [INFO]: 227 packages are looking for funding
                                 run `npm fund` for details
2023-10-06T19:20:15.742Z [INFO]: 4 vulnerabilities (3 low, 1 moderate)
                                 To address issues that do not require attention, run:
                                 npm audit fix
                                 To address all issues (including breaking changes), run:
                                 npm audit fix --force
                                 Run `npm audit` for details.
2023-10-06T19:20:15.756Z [INFO]: # Completed phase: preBuild
                                 # Starting phase: build
2023-10-06T19:20:15.756Z [INFO]: # Executing command: npm run build
2023-10-06T19:20:16.116Z [INFO]: > grateful-galaxy@0.0.1 build
                                 > astro build
2023-10-06T19:20:16.234Z [WARNING]: Node.js v16.19.0 is not supported by Astro!
                                    Please upgrade Node.js to a supported version: ">=18.14.1"
2023-10-06T19:20:16.236Z [INFO]: AWS CodeBuild CI Environment Detected!
                                 Additional steps may be needed to set your Node.js version:
2023-10-06T19:20:16.237Z [INFO]: Documentation: https://docs.astro.build/guides/deploy
2023-10-06T19:20:16.244Z [ERROR]: !!! Build failed
2023-10-06T19:20:16.245Z [ERROR]: !!! Non-Zero Exit Code detected
2023-10-06T19:20:16.245Z [INFO]: # Starting environment caching...
2023-10-06T19:20:16.245Z [INFO]: # Uploading environment cache artifact...
2023-10-06T19:20:16.357Z [INFO]: # Uploaded environment cache artifact
```